# Login failed while fetching api-data in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In backend `data` is coming properly. But in fronted, `login-failed` even user enter right username and password in ReactJS.

I think i have made somewhere wrong in my code, i have no idea where i made wrong. It would be great, if anybody could help me out what i am trying to solve is. thank you so much in advance.

enpoint url: http://localhost:8000/api/login

```
export default class App  extends Component{

  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state ={
          username: "",
          password: "",
      }
      this.onFormSubmit = this.onFormSubmit.bind(this)
      this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this)
      //  this.fileUpload = this.fileUpload.bind(this)
  }

  onFormSubmit(values){
    console.log(values);

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("username", values.username);
    formData.append("password", values.password);


      const options = {
          method: 'POST',
          body: formData
      };

      fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/login', options);
  }



 render(){
    return(

    <div>

                           <form class="row contact_form" onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>

                                <div class="col-md-12 form-group p_star">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name"
                                        placeholder="Username"/>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-12 form-group p_star">
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password"
                                        placeholder="Password"/>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-12 form-group">

                                    <button type="submit" value="submit" class="btn_3">
                                        log in
                                    </button>

                                </div>
                            </form>

    </div>

    )
 }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to verify token in React? You send correct username and password to backend and it will verify it and sends token to your react app. You store that token in your app and attach it in header in every api call.

Comment: I assume you are receiving token from backend. Do you want to confirm it is a success or not, Is that it ?

Comment: yes. i want to verify the success token whenever user will enter right `username` and `password`. @ViswanathLekshmanan

Comment: Could you explain what do you meant by verify ? It's probably a JWT token from server. Why do you want to verify that ? Since the API returned 200 status its a valid token.

Comment: yeah i know. exactly! but when i am entering right `username` and `password` then login failed in ReactJs. i think i have made something wrong in my code. i have no idea where i made the error in my code. @ViswanathLekshmanan

Comment: @bounty then check your credentials..

Comment: @Azima i have already double checked eerything, data is passing perfect in backend. whenever i verifying in fronted then `login failed`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have made little bit mistake. just comment out this line. `this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this)`